# Custom enumerate text is not left aligned

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I have a list that I am generating using the `enumerate` environment and the `enumitem` package, so that I can specify custom text before the counter: Step 1, Step 2, etc. For some reason the text shows up out in the left-hand margin rather than being left-aligned (or indented) with the rest of the document as I would have expected. In other words, it seems to just keep the item number in the same horizontal location and tack on the text to the left so that it sticks out into the margin:

[image]

I would have expected the list to instead shift to the right so that the text "Step" started where the "1." would have started. How do i fix this behavior?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Step \arabic*:]
\item Sample ...
\item Map from ...
\item Compute texture dependent properties...
\item Map ... 
\item Compute ...
\item Define ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The labels are set up so that they end a certain distance from the text, so your labels are sticking out into the left margin because they are quite "wide". You can fix this by adding `leftmargin=*` to arguments of your `enumerate` environment. This makes the items line up with the left left-margin.

**Edit** If, in addition, you want the items indented a "standard" amount (which, from the manual seems to be `1em`) you can do this but setting `labelindent=1em`.:

[image]

Here's your full code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Step \arabic*:,leftmargin=*,labelindent=1em]
\item Sample ...
\item Map from ...
\item Compute texture dependent properties...
\item Map ...
\item Compute ...
\item Define ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I would do if I wanted the items indented the same amount as they would normally be without the "Step" text? (I assume there is a default indent distance)

Comment: @okj I've updated the answer to show how to do this.