# How to make numbered list where the number is not the first part of the title

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, enumerate

I would like to make a list of goals like so:

```
Goal 1:
Do some stuff.

Goal 2:
Some other stuff.

Goal 3:
etc
```

I can use \begin{enumerate} to make a numbered list, however I would like each number prefixed with the text "Goal", and I would like it as a different line, more like a section heading. I would rather not type out "Goal 1:" etc for each item as these items will likely be reorganised at some stage.

Is there a way to make a numbered list with text titles for each item which include the item number?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! E.g. the enumerate or enumitem packages allow you to do precisely that. For an explicit example see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238942/121799

Answer (score 0):

Combining the information from the links in the comments I now have an answer thank you. This uses the package enumitem and has some untidy label formatting:

In the preamble define a new list and format the list items:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Goallist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[Goallist]{label={\\\\ Goal \arabic*:\\}}
```

Then use this new list definition as normally would be done with enumerate:

```
\begin{Goallist}
  \item Text for first goal goes here.
  \item Text for next goal goes here.
\end{Goallist}
```

This returns the desired output:

```
Goal 1:
Text for first goal goes here.

Goal 2:
Text for next goal goes here.
```